# How to display text when we toggle in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I would like to show a text when user clicks on an icon. I have the following code block, but it is wrong.
Can someone correct me:

```js
<a class="icon-question-sign help_popup"
   onclick="javascript:$('#callback_help').toggle('fast', function() {
     $('#callback_help').html('xx');
   })">
</a>
```

Comment: It seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/dfaevzbs/ What is the problem?

Comment: A very bad idea to use jQuery in inline event handler.

Comment: @Satpal that's for sure.

Comment: i dont know, why but above my code block didnt work. Rakesh's code is working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kj4uhex0/)**

You have to inlude jQuery library if you have not included :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Second you can try like this :

HTML :

```
<a class="icon-question-sign help_popup"></a>
<div id="callback_help"></div>
```

Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

       $('.help_popup').click(function(){

            $('#callback_help').toggle('fast', function() {
                  $('#callback_help').html('xx');
            });
       });

});

</script>
```